# Adding a column in relation table without foreign key-Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I am using two tables namely seller and product, and I am relating this table by using a relation table called seller-product in which I am seller-id and product-id which are foreign keys and I need to add another column as rate which is not a foreign key can I do like that. I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Could you please add some code and also specify things you have tried so that we can help better..

Answer (score 0):

Just add the column:

```
alter table seller_product add rate integer;
```

Assuming you have already created the table, e.g. using:

```
create table seller_product
(
   seller_id integer not null references seller,
   product_id integer not null references product,
   primary key (seller_id, product_id)
);
```

To do everything together when creating the table:

```
create table seller_product
(
   seller_id  integer not null references seller,
   product_id integer not null references product,
   rate       integer,
   primary key (seller_id, product_id)
);
```